# How to vertically align nested list

Tags: css

I've two nested list:

```
<ul>
    <li>First item
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">some item</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">some item</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">some item</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Second item
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">some item</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">some item</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">some item</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want my first list level was horizontally aligned, and the second one's vertically aligned.

I tried the css :

```
ul > li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

But it also apply to the second level (a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RDeBB/301/)). How can I do ?

NB : I also notice that bullet disappears...

Comment: You could add an id to the second list.

Comment: list display is : list-item, if you reset it to inline-block or else then no more bullets will be shown

Comment: add this to your css `li:nth-child(2) li{display: block;}`

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/RDeBB/302/

Comment: @Ejay ?? should it not be : `ul > li >ul > li {
   display: list-item;
}` to get bullets back as well ?

Comment: @BeatAlex for the bullets it would be : http://jsfiddle.net/RDeBB/303/

Comment: Good job @GCyrillus, you got it, thanks ; )

Comment: that was a team job :)

Comment: @GCyrillus yep absolutely. I was only focusing on vertical/horizontal align thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  ul > li > ul >li {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: in comments we agreed with display:list-item :)

Comment: Sure I didn't noticed, answerd it fast while I was working =P My Bad ;)

Answer (score 0):

hi Fractaliste try the following code and please let me know if any thing else you need

```
<style type="text/css">
.navigation ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style: none;
}
.navigation li {
float: left;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-top: 8px;
}
.navigation li a {
text-decoration:none;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
}
.navigation li ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
height:30px;
}
.navigation li:hover ul
{
left: 0;
width:160px;
}
.navigation li:hover ul li
{
   background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
margin-bottom: 3px;
padding: 8px 10px 1px 10px;
}

</style>


<div class="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">menu1</a>
<ul>
<li>sub menu item 1</li>
<li>sub menu item 2</li>
<li>sub menu item 3</li>
<li>sub menu item 4</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="menu2.html">menu2</a>
<ul>
<li>sub menu item 1</li>
<li>sub menu item 2</li>
<li>sub menu item 3</li>
<li>sub menu item 4</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="menu3.html">menu3</a>
<ul>
<li>sub menu item 1</li>
<li>sub menu item 2</li>
<li>sub menu item 3</li>
<li>sub menu item 4</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="menu3.html">menu3</a>
<ul>
<li>sub menu item 1</li>
<li>sub menu item 2</li>
<li>sub menu item 3</li>
<li>sub menu item 4</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="menu4.html">menu4</a>

<ul>
<li>sub menu item 1</li>
<li>sub menu item 2</li>
<li>sub menu item 3</li>
<li>sub menu item 4</li>
</ul>
</li></ul>

</div>
```